# How do I implement a super long rate limit?

Tags: nginx

For most of my website I have a normal rate limit of 1 request/second:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
```

I now need a limit of 10 per day for a certain location. Is that possible?

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=loginmin:10m rate=1tth;
```

I get:  invalid rate "rate=1tth"

Comment: `tth` is not a valid measurement. How did you come up with this?

Comment: @herrbischoff http://blog.nkhost.net/notes/nginx-limit-the-request-processing-rate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the article you linked:

> After source code review I’ve found a way to decrease minimal rate down to 86 requests per day. Patch below adds ability to use next configuration directive:

There are two things to learn from this:

1. You will need to patch the source code of Nginx for the approach in the article to work.
2. Even with the patch in place, you will only be able to throttle it down to 86 requests/day.

Therefore we can conclude that what you are looking for is currently not possible with Nginx alone.

My suggestion is to use `fail2ban` for this purpose. You can create a custom jail:

```
# /usr/local/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/nginx-extreme-ratelimit.local

[nginx-extreme-ratelimit]
enabled  = true
filter   = nginx-ratelimit
action   = pf <-- or ufw, ipfilter, ipfw, whatever firewall you use
logpath  = /var/log/nginx-access.log
findtime  = 86400
maxretry = 10
bantime  = 86400
```

And a respective custom filter:

```
# /usr/local/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-ratelimit.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^\s*\[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ limiting requests, excess: [\d\.]+ by zone "(?:%(ngx_limit_req_zones)s)", client: <HOST>,

ignoreregex =

datepattern = {^LN-BEG}
```

The `failregex` obviously has to be adjusted to match the access string.

Additionally, set up a cron job that runs at 12 pm every day to unban the IP address:

```
00 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/fail2ban-client set nginx-extreme-ratelimit unbanip 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score -2):

With [nginx-mod](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build), you can simply put:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=10r/d;
```

Of course, your traffic should be small enough (~less than 160K visitors to the rate limited resources) with this config.

Or you'll need to adjust zone's memory size to be large enough to accommodate all visitor IP addresses to the rate limited resources within 24 hrs.